# Why is my streamed mp3 file longer/ larger than the original in the S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, stream

I'm trying to stream mp3 files from an AWS S3 Bucket via an express API.

The app connects to AWS just fine and I can download/ stream files from the bucket. But I noticed while testing that once the stream has finished that my file is longer than the original uploaded to the S3 bucket. Playing the file back, the sound jumps around quite a bit. I've run it a few times and is consistently larger than the original file but I'm not sure why. This is the first time I've ever worked with streaming data of any kind but it feels like I'm missing something obvious. I think it might have to do with meta data around the chunks of information but I'm not sure. I've tried searching around why this might be the case but I'm not sure what vocabulary to use to search for the  answers I need.

Here is the code I'm using to stream the file from AWS, piping it directly into the response object for the API call.

```js
      s3Client
      .getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log("There was an error finding object: ", err);
      })
      .createReadStream()
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("File Stream error: ", err);
      })
      .on("data", (chunk) => {
        total += chunk.length;
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("All done");
        console.log("Total Streamed MB: ", total / 1000000);
      })
      .pipe(response);
```

Here is an example of the file size I'm talking about:
[Console output showing streamed file much larger than original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONJXq.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging through the AWS github errors I came across a few people with similar issues. There is an issue with:

```
s3Client
.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log("There was an error finding object: ", err);
})
.createReadStream()
```

According to this [comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/959#issuecomment-209066648) having the error callback in the `getObject` call, then chaining `createReadStream` creates two requests to AWS that will pipe into the same response. Which is why the file was close to doubling in size. Removing that callback the file streams as I expected.